# Double integral of exponential function with power and rational functions

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am having trouble evaluating the integral 
$\int _0^2\int _{max\left(x,1\right)}^2e^{\frac{x}{y}+y^2}dydx$. 
Applying Fubini's Theorem to simplify the $max(x,1)$ function, gives me $\int _1^2\int _0^2e^{\frac{x}{y}+y^2}dxdy$ (I think I did it correctly?). However when trying to further integrate I get absurdly long integrals with multiple levels of integration by parts required which makes me think I am overcomplicating the problem... 
If anyone could shed some light on how to approach such an integral that would be amazing.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int _0^2\int _{\max\left(x,1\right)}^2e^{\frac{x}{y}+y^2}dydx&=\int _0^1\int _{\max\left(x,1\right)}^2e^{\frac{x}{y}+y^2}dydx+\int _1^2\int _{\max\left(x,1\right)}^2e^{\frac{x}{y}+y^2}dydx\\
&=\int _0^1\int _{1}^2e^{\frac{x}{y}+y^2}dydx+\int_1^2\int _{x}^2e^{\frac{x}{y}+y^2}dydx\\
&=\int _1^2\int _0^1e^{\frac{x}{y}+y^2}dxdy+\int_1^2\int _1^ye^{\frac{x}{y}+y^2}dxdy
\end{split}
\end{equation}